# google maps distance calculation issue

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I am fetching nearest lat long from database on the base of my current location.My current location

```
      latitude:  32.5033801 
      longitude:  74.49884399999999
```

I find this form https://ctrlq.org/maps/where/ . I am using this query

`SELECT lat,lng, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(32.5033801) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(74.49884399999999) ) + sin( radians(32.5033801) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores HAVING distance < 60 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20`

This query giving me distance from my current location to **Model Town Rd, Gujranwala, Pakistan** 47.2 KM . but google map giving me 54.9KM. Now there is a difference of about 7km which i think is too much.

I have attached two images first is the result of my query and second is result of google maps

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are two type of distance between two coordinates i.e. line distance and driving distance, you are calculating line distance and you need driving distance.

Comment: how can i find driving distance from query

Comment: I see 58.0 and 68.4, shouldn't you complain about those, too?

Comment: Note that you have to backtrack from Model Town Rd., that consumes perhaps 2 km of the discrepancy.  Then another 5 km at the leg near the destination.

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of distance between two coordinates i.e. **line distance** and **driving distance**, you are calculating **line distance** and you need **driving distance**.

Here is the documentation to help you out :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters

and here is an example :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix

Hope it helps !

Comment: can i calcute driving distance from database like i am calculation line distance

Answer (score 0):

Your query calculates distance between two points. Google Maps is giving you driving directions.